# sbuild errors "but it is not going to be installed"

Tags: packaging, cross-compilation

My goal is to cross-build debian package, so I test on something simple - ncurses.

I follow this guide consisting of two commands:
https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/UsingMultiArch.
Run these commands:

```
xbuild-chroot-setup precise /srv/chroots/precise-cross
cp /usr/share/doc/sbuild/examples/example.sbuildrc /root/.sbuildrc
sbuild-update --keygen
sbuild --host=armhf -d precise -c precise-i386-sbuild ncurses_5.9-4
```

And get the message:

```
...
Cross-deps: Running apt-get -aarmhf build-dep ncurses
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 debhelper : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: binutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for ncurses could not be satisfied.
Failed to get cross build-deps
...
```

On first I thought to chroot in and install debhelper manually, but it messed even more. So it's not right path.

```
...
Unpacking gcc-4.6-multilib:armhf (from .../gcc4.6-multilib_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_armhf.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp-4.6_4.6.3-1ubuntu5_armhf.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cpp_4%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
E: Failed to process build dependencies
Failed to get cross build-deps
...
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here is that those package are either not available in the repo or not compatible with the dependencies. You can try adding a repo which can satisfy all the dependencies of that package.